# Remove special character chr(191) and others SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, special-characters

Bit novice to the unix scripting and Oracle commands so be easy...

I have a field which gets populated with incorrect characters and specially the chr(191) ' inverted ? sign'..

I had this sample code

```
UPDATE rc.rc_descripton
SET desc_description = 
                        (
                         CASE 
                            WHEN desc_description LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' 
                                  THEN Replace(REPLACE( desc_description, SUBSTRING( desc_description, PATINDEX('%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,^,&,%,*,(,)]%', desc_description), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
                            ELSE desc_description
                          END
                         )
```

Though my original UPDATE command was :-

```
UPDATE rc.rc_description
SET    desc_description  = REPLACE(desc_description, CHR(191), ' ')
WHERE  desc_description LIKE '%' || CHR(191) || '%'
```

I want to incorporate the above code to the main sample code i have posted above.

I did found an unix script that was being used earlier :

```
# Replace offending characters with the intending/valid characters 

sed s/–/-/g $1 | sed s/’/\'/g | sed s/‘/\'/g | sed s//\'/g | sed s//\'/g | sed s//\"/g | sed s//\"/g | sed s/“/\"/g | sed s/”/\"/g | sed s/—/-/g | sed s//-/g | sed s/…/.../g | sed s/‑/-/g | sed 's/½/1\/2/g' | sed 's/¼/1\/4/g' | sed 's/¾/3\/4/g' | sed 's/· //g' | sed s/°/./g | sed s/•/*/g | sed s/ //g > $1.out
```

But I cant translate the unix code to the Oracle update command..

please advise of the correct UPDATE command to cater to all set of special characters as above and to take into consideration the CHR(191) too...

sincerely,
A.B.

Comment: Inverted ? is extended ASCII 168, not 191? Perhaps you are just seeing that symbol because your client is not set up to display all (UTF) characters properly. What character set are your database, client and operating system session? And are you really sure you want to be stripping put special characters and reducing your stored text to US7ASCII?

Comment: Original txt 

. Unit 1 has stated, “I’M SO SORRY”. XXXX unable to obtain a full version from Unit 1 due to her injuries and QAS request that

Converted text :

has stated, ¿I¿M SO SORRY¿. XXXX unable to obtain a full version from Unit 1 due

So, ideally i do want to see the original text, but for 9i version i cannot seem to get any equivalent functions as used by 10g or higher.

Comment: What is your NLS_LANG or operating system locale set to? And your database characterset? That looks like a display issue - your client isn't displaying the unicode characters properly. Presumably you have 'smart' quote marks like `” “ ’ ‘` in the stored string and your client doesn't know how to render them, which is usually a settings issue.

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE              AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY                AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY                $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY      AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS    .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET      WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_CALENDAR                GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT      DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_SORT           BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET     AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION  9.2.0.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I got the following statement working for me :-

```
 select desc_description,
  length(dbms_lob.substr(desc_description, 3500, 1)) len,
  lengthb(dbms_lob.substr(desc_description, 3500, 1)) lenb,

  convert(replace(translate(dbms_lob.substr(desc_description, 3500, 1), ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-=`~!@#$%^&*()_+,./<>?;'':"[]\{}|',' '), ' ', ''),'us7ascii') bad_char_replaced,

  rawtohex(convert(replace(translate(dbms_lob.substr(desc_description, 3500, 1), ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-=`~!@#$%^&*()_+,./<>?;'':"[]\{}|',' '), ' ', ''),'us7ascii')) bad_char_replaced_hex ,
  -------
  convert(dbms_lob.substr(desc_description, 3500, 1),'us7ascii') converted
  -------
  from rc.rc_description

  WHERE  desc_description LIKE '%' || CHR(191) || '%' and
  desc_cras_number = '20140096849';
```

The before text is :
vehicleï¿½s B pillar has ......

The After text is :
vehiclei??s B pillar has ......

Can I get the above query to remove these ??? to apostrophe or double quotes ? or if that screws the data then jst use an empty space.

Answer (score -2):

Try this Replace the input with your string and the regex is for alphanumeric you can manipulate it easily
T-SQL SYNTAX

```
DECLARE @input AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '124567890qwertyuioopasdfghjklzx cvbnm,;#$%^&*(!)$^'
DECLARE @output AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = @input
DECLARE @RegexString AS NVARCHAR(max) = '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]'

WHILE PATINDEX('%'+@RegexString+'%',@output)>0
BEGIN
    SET     @output=  STUFF(@output,PATINDEX('%'+@RegexString+'%',@output),1,'')
    PRINT   @output
END

SELECT @input , @output
```

Comment: That isn't Oracle syntax.

Comment: Yes, I am using 9i so even REGEX does not work... 
Tried using OWA_PATTERN.AMATCH but in vain, any clue on what can i use for Oracle 9i version equivalent